# Why is Ubuntu 20.04 not registering ethernet on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: boot, 20.04, ethernet, raspberrypi

When the Raspberry Pi boots up, Ubuntu 20.04 says the following:
*Net:  No ethernet found.
starting USB...
No working controllers found*
It continues to boot up, but this means that I can not install a desktop environment on it. The ethernet port and cable work fine, and the Raspberry Pi ethernet jack lights up when the cable is plugged in. How do I get ethernet to be recognized?
Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem with Raspberry Pi 4B on Ubuntu 21.04. The eth0 connection isn't detected by Gnome Settings. The 1Gbit ethernet cable works fine on my laptop ubuntu 21.04. I swaped the raspberypi with the store, thinking was a hardware problem, but the new board got the same problem.